# Displaying an image from a list of 13 in Shiny App based on pickerInput selection

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app and have 2 png images for each of the 13 ecoregions of california and I am trying to display them based on whichever ecoregion is selected with pickerInput. I am just trying to display 1 image from each of the 13 ecoregions for now. My names_fire_count_hist is made up of 13 of the ecoregions where the name is for example Cascades and the value is fire_count_histogram_cascades, as seen in the image. The fire_count_hist_list is a list of 13 of the png images where each image is fire_count_histogram_[[ecoregion]] (ex: fire_count_histogram_cascades). Any help much appreciated.

I get an error: character vector argument expected in the statistics tab panel.

Here is the code in my UI:

```
tabPanel(title = "Statistics", icon = icon("chart-simple"),
                      
                      # sidebarLayout
                      #                                  sidebarLayout(
                      
                      sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                                   selectInput(inputId = "ecoregion_stats_type_input",
                                               label = "Select ecoregion:",
                                               choices = names_fire_count_hist, # names_gde
                                               selected = 'gde_northern_basin',
                                               multiple = F        
                                   ), # END pickerInput
                      ), # End sidebarPanel 
                      
                      # Stats Main Panel----
                      mainPanel(
                        imageOutput("stats"),                        
                      ) # End mainPanel     
             ), # End tabPanel
```

Code in my Server:

```
stat_selected <- input$ecoregion_stats_type_input
stat_selected2 = gsub('fire_count_histogram_', '', stat_selected)

names_fire_count_hist2 = gsub('fire_count_histogram_', '', names_fire_count_hist)

wfire_count_hist = which(names_fire_count_hist2 == stat_selected2)
wfire_count_hist = names_fire_count_hist[wfire_count_hist]
print(wfire_count_hist)

  stats_reactive <- reactive({
    
    print(input$ecoregion_stats_type_input)
    req(!is.null(input$ecoregion_stats_type_input))
    stat <- img(fire_count_hist_list[[wfire_count_hist]])
    stat
  })
  
  output$stats <- renderImage({
     
    req(!is.null(stats_reactive()))
    stats_reactive()
    
  })
```